# Python pandas decrease backfill until reach a certain number based on interval

Tags: python, pandas, decrement

I have the following dataframe called df,

```
date          flag1 flag2 flag3 flag4…
2020-12-31
2021-01-01                          
2021-01-02                   1
2021-01-03
2021-01-04
2021-01-05            1                
2021-01-06                        1
2021-01-07
2021-01-08
2021-01-09
2021-01-10
2021-01-11     1                  1
2021-01-12
```

I want to do a backfill when a 1 appears in any column, and fill backwards until a number appears or failing that, backfill til a set number.

So let’s say the set number to reduce o to is 0 and the decrement is 0.1, it should look like this,

```
date         flag1  flag2  flag3  flag4…
2020-12-31           0.5    0.8    0.4
2021-01-01   0.0     0.6    0.9    0.5
2021-01-02   0.1     0.7    1.0    0.6
2021-01-03   0.2     0.8           0.7
2021-01-04   0.3     0.9           0.8
2021-01-05   0.4     1.0           0.9
2021-01-06   0.5                   1.0
2021-01-07   0.6                   0.6
2021-01-08   0.7                   0.7
2021-01-09   0.8                   0.8
2021-01-10   0.9                   0.9
2021-01-11   1.0                   1.0
2021-01-12
```

Can this be achieved with pandas? I want to be able to set the decrement amount and the limit for example the above would be 0.1 and 0.

I know that this command can increment the values backwards:

```
df1 = df1[::-1].fillna(method='ffill')
(df1 + (df1 == df1.shift()).cumsum()).sort_index()
```

But that’s not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try using `iloc` to change the values based on the indices where the column value is equals to 1.0:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def process_data(c, n):
  for idx in reversed(np.where(c==1)[0]):
    c.iloc[np.arange(idx)[::-1][:n.shape[0]]] = n[idx-1::-1][::-1]
    c.iat[idx] = 1.0
  return c
df = df.apply(lambda r: process_data(r, np.linspace(1.0, 0.0, num=11)[1:]))
```

```
             flag1  flag2  flag3  flag4
date                                   
2020-12-31     NaN    0.5    0.8    0.4
2021-01-01     0.0    0.6    0.9    0.5
2021-01-02     0.1    0.7    1.0    0.6
2021-01-03     0.2    0.8    NaN    0.7
2021-01-04     0.3    0.9    NaN    0.8
2021-01-05     0.4    1.0    NaN    0.9
2021-01-06     0.5    NaN    NaN    1.0
2021-01-07     0.6    NaN    NaN    0.6
2021-01-08     0.7    NaN    NaN    0.7
2021-01-09     0.8    NaN    NaN    0.8
2021-01-10     0.9    NaN    NaN    0.9
2021-01-11     1.0    NaN    NaN    1.0
2021-01-12     NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: It is indeed so.

Comment: hey man thanks for this, is it also possible to decrease it back to 0 after you reach the 1?, so from 0 to 1 to 0 again.

Comment: A few changes would need be made to the current implementation, but I think you can figure it out ;)

Answer (score 1):

First are created groups by cumulative sums with `ffill` and limit parameter and then per each group are subtract from right side `10`, divide `10` and set `NaN` if original values is missing:

```
decr = 0.1
vals = 10

f = lambda x: x.groupby(x).cumcount(ascending=False).rsub(vals).mul(decr).where(x.notna())
df1 = df1.cumsum()[::-1].ffill(limit=vals)[::-1].apply(f)
print (df1)
            flag1  flag2  flag3  flag4
date                                  
2020-12-31    NaN    0.5    0.8    0.4
2021-01-01    0.0    0.6    0.9    0.5
2021-01-02    0.1    0.7    1.0    0.6
2021-01-03    0.2    0.8    NaN    0.7
2021-01-04    0.3    0.9    NaN    0.8
2021-01-05    0.4    1.0    NaN    0.9
2021-01-06    0.5    NaN    NaN    1.0
2021-01-07    0.6    NaN    NaN    0.6
2021-01-08    0.7    NaN    NaN    0.7
2021-01-09    0.8    NaN    NaN    0.8
2021-01-10    0.9    NaN    NaN    0.9
2021-01-11    1.0    NaN    NaN    1.0
2021-01-12    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

More general solution:

```
decr = 0.1
start = 1
end = 0

r = np.arange(start, end, -decr)
print (r)
[1.  0.9 0.8 0.7 0.6 0.5 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.1]

vals = len(r)

f = lambda x: x.groupby(x).cumcount(ascending=False).rsub(vals).mul(decr).where(x.notna())
df1 = df1.where(df1.eq(1)).cumsum()[::-1].ffill(limit=vals)[::-1].apply(f)
print (df1)
            flag1  flag2  flag3  flag4
date                                  
2020-12-31    NaN    0.5    0.8    0.4
2021-01-01    0.0    0.6    0.9    0.5
2021-01-02    0.1    0.7    1.0    0.6
2021-01-03    0.2    0.8    NaN    0.7
2021-01-04    0.3    0.9    NaN    0.8
2021-01-05    0.4    1.0    NaN    0.9
2021-01-06    0.5    NaN    NaN    1.0
2021-01-07    0.6    NaN    NaN    0.6
2021-01-08    0.7    NaN    NaN    0.7
2021-01-09    0.8    NaN    NaN    0.8
2021-01-10    0.9    NaN    NaN    0.9
2021-01-11    1.0    NaN    NaN    1.0
2021-01-12    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: @MustafaAydın - yes, it should be slowier, because `groupby` is used.